# How to translate the word "cени" to English

Tags: перевод

In other words how to translate this line:
`Ласточка с весною в сени к нам летит`?

Comment: here is an article on wikipedia about "сени" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entryway

Comment: перевод с русского на английский не является темой данного стека.

Answer (score 12):

Although one swallow does not a summer make, it might be enough for spring.

Cени is a kind of non-residential inner porch, typically used for storage of coats and shoes, though sometimes you might have guests sleep there in the summer. Often it separates two wings of a house, and opens on to an actual (outer) porch (крыльцо), if there is one. I think mudroom is probably the closest English equivalent. Vestibule or entryway are two other possibilities. The only problem with mudroom is that it is often a secondary entrance to the house, which is usually not the case with сени.

In the photo below, you can see the heavy door leading into the main house as well as the doorway to outside.

[image: mudroom?]

Answer (score 0):

porch... Something like "It's spring. Swallow sits on our porch". Obviously, my translation lacks poetic beauty :)